# What is another phrase for "start here"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for words and phrases with similar meaning to "start here" or "get started".  The thesaurus is not helping because I'm not looking specifically for synonyms of "start".

I want a phrase that connotes the identification of a location/resource that is:

- good for beginners
- contains introductory knowledge
- teaches what is needed to put the learner on the right path

What else means the same as or something similar to "start here"?

Comment: [Introduction](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=introduction&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=yjRRT6jMCo6z8QPYlPnwBQ&ved=0CCYQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3b6b42e17dd83c7b&biw=1264&bih=902)

Comment: I'm aware of the word *introduction*, it doesn't suit my needs as I'd like something that can serve as a metaphorical signpost, not simply a heading.

Comment: Well, I did vote to close as "General Reference", but in light of that I'd still vote to close - probably as "Too Localised", but it's also "Off-Topic" (belongs on writers.se), and "Not Constructive" (you're just inviting a plethora of metaphors). Having said that, consider the one on a Monopoly board - **GO**.

Comment: Voting to close as not constructive / off topic because this is just a guessing game question, and not well suited to the Q&A format (i.e. has no specific answer.)  There are a ton of possibilities.  "Start Here" seems pretty good itself.  "Tutorial" is another option.

Comment: @Lynn So the other 235 [tag:phrase-requests] are... not not-constructive, somehow?

Comment: @NickC - Many of them are, yes.  See [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) for discussion, and see how many of those phrase requests in your link are closed.   Here is an example of a [constructive one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/is-there-a-term-for-simultaneous-snow-and-rain) because it is not a open-ended "try to guess what word I'm looking for" discussion but a request for a phrase that either exists or does not.

Answer (score 2):

I like ***Square One***.  Other options might include:

- Starting Point
- Starting Line
- Starting Gate
- On Your Mark!
- Quick Start Guide
- Orientation Guide

Answer (score 2):

A *primer* is text that is:

- good for beginners
- contains introductory knowledge
- teaches what is needed to put the learner on the right path

Or how about *The Fundamentals*, *The Basics*, *Groundwork*, or *Foundations*. These, of course, are all noun forms, but they imply that you start here and then once you've learned these things, you move on to more complex things.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

- Let's Go (depending on the voice you're looking for)
- Jump Right In
- Diving In/Dive In
- First Step
- All Aboard

Answer (score 1):

Using the number "101", which I presume is a reference to college course numberings, so if your thing was fishing, instead of "Introduction to Fishing" you can call it "Fishing 101"