# Partially melted snow on ground

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there any word or neat expression for fallen snow on ground that doesn't hold shape anymore (because the temperature has risen, ...) and it's just this unpleasant Slurpee-like mass? This is often on roads or pavements where cars or feet move the snow, so it in addition becomes all grey-ish.

I'd use it like:

> It's not white Christmas when the snow outside is all --- !

Comment: *Dirty / grungy*?

Comment: Speaking to you from tropical southern Minnesota, there is no single term.  Basically, ad-hoc descriptions will be used, based on the appearance of the snow and the intent of the speaker.

Comment: The word we use is Sludge. or Sludgy

Comment: *slush* or, if mostly just water, *snow melt*

Comment: You might also simply use the word *old*, which would likely inspire such mental imagery in those used to snow.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: I don't think so. "Old snow" doesn't (usually) include the partially melted aspect.  Old snow would be snow that's been around a while, and has settled & compacted, as the individual flakes lose their shape and sublime into something more closely approching small pellets of ice.

Comment: Alright, you're probably more winter-accustomed than me, so I cede the point unless others disagree

Comment: Related; [Is there a term for simultaneous snow and rain?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/is-there-a-term-for-simultaneous-snow-and-rain)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you just want *slush*, defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slush) as:

> a : partly melted or watery snow

So:

> It's not a white Christmas when the snow outside is all slushy!

Comment: [Slushy](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Slush_%28beverage%29) is also the more generic term for Slurpee-like drinks the OP referenced.

Comment: And if the snow falls out of the sky in this condition, it's *sleet*. An archaic term for slush is apparently *lapper*. (Did you know that English has more than a dozen terms to describe snow? True story.)

Comment: Actually sleet is small, round ice pellets. Slush is different.

Comment: @DonBranson Sleet is "slushy snow" in British English. Other variants of English refer to sleet as this hail-like snow that you are mentioning.

Comment: @DonBranson The OED defines sleet as "*Snow which has been partially thawed by falling through an atmosphere of a temperature a little above freezing-point, usually accompanied by rain or snow.*" And in my corner of the upper-Midwest, *sleet* generally turns to *slush* when it hits the ground. I would describe "small, round ice pellets" as *hail* (size small).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleet

Comment: @1006a [Graupel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graupel) might describe the "small, round ice pellets" you mention.  Hail forms in summer storms.  Graupel forms in winter.

Comment: @1006a: English has far more than a dozen words for snow, at least if you're a skiier.

Comment: @jamesqf Eh, it was meant to be a linguistics joke; not very clear, I guess. Maybe "English has X words for snow" would have been more obvious. Probably should have left it out altogether.

Comment: *Sleet* is also commonly used in England to mean rain and hail mixed together. This is the small sort of hail properly known as ice pellets rather than big hailstones (which we rarely see).

Comment: And according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail "[sleet and hail] are often confused."

Comment: Could you all please take this discussion to chat so I don't get pinged all the time?